# Compiling a C++ program - "the program gcc can be found in the following packages"

Tags: compiling, gcc, c++

I tried to compile a cpp program through the terminal on 13.04 but got this message:

```
npg@NPG-ideaPad-S210:~$ gcc -o comp-LCG.cpp
The program 'gcc' can be found in the following packages:
 * gcc
 * pentium-builder
Try: sudo apt-get install <selected package>
```

What should I do ?

Comment: This says you don't have GCC installed. It already says what to do: `sudo apt-get install gcc`

Answer (score 2):

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential
```

1. Enter this command in a terminal window to open the gedit text editor.

   ```
   gedit progcpp.cpp
   ```
2. To compile the program enter the command given below in a terminal window.

   ```
   g++ progcpp.cpp -o progcpp
   ```
3. Enter the command given below to run the program.

   ```
   ./progcpp
   ```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you open a terminal and do:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential
```

Then try again.